# MongoDB: after copying data from another server, not querying

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a production server where we have a nodejs application and a MongoDB database. We have a virtual machine in the server and the application and the DB are located there. Now, we want to build a develop environment in another server. Because of that, we have copied the virtual machine to another server.

But now, when our application queries the MongoDB, it doesn't get any data. However, it connects to the database, the logs of the mongodb and the logs form the application show it to us. Moreover, when we query the DB throughout the mongo shell, we get the data. The application uses the mongoose to connect to the database.

Becuase of that, we have tried copying the data for the production server as:

1. Executing a mongoexport in the production server and then a mongoimport in the other machines, but nothing.
2. Executing a mongodump in the production server and then a mongorestore in the other machines, but nothing.

The characteristics of the servers are as follows:

- OS for both servers: Ubuntu 16.04
- MongoDB version: 3.2.11

Then, because I couldn't get the data, I tried to copy it to my localhost. But this isn't the issue, this is only additional information:

- OS of my PC: Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit)
- MongoDB version: 3.2.4

Comment: First though are you sure it is compatible to open a data created in `3.2.11` using `3.2.4` database? (so lower version)

Comment: This really doesn't tell anyone anything. If you get no results then something has changed. You either named things differently, are pointing to the wrong place or you did not assign the correct permissions. You would have some feedback. You need to provide more information on your debugging, and really should try to minimally reproduce the case. See  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Probably it wouldn't, but the issue isn't that. The problem is that I have two identical servers, I copied the data from one server to another, and I can't query the data. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I'll suggest to look into mongodb log.